# Python : Get count of successfully matched groups for regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture data and numbers from a string in python. The string is a measurement from an RF sensor so it might be corrupted from bad transmission. Strings from the sensor look like this PA1015.7 TMPA20.53 HUM76.83.

My re is :

```
s= re.search('^(\D+)([0-9.]+'),message)
```

Now before I proceed I want to check if I truly received exactly two matches properly or if the string is garbled.

So I tried :

```
len(s)
```

But that errors out :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type '_sre.SRE_Match' has no len()
```

I do need access to the match group elements for processing later. (I think that eliminates findall)

```
key= s.group(1)
data= s.group(2)
```

What's missing?

Comment: "I do need access to the match group elements for processing later. (I think that eliminates findall)" - Why would this eliminate findall? You will be able to access the matched groups as findall returns a list of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `search`, you should use `findall` instead:

```
s = re.findall('(\D+)([0-9.]+)',message)
print("matched " + str(len(s)))
```

`search` only returns whether there is or is no match in the input string, in the form of a boolean.

Comment: It will be better to remove the leading caret `^` to match multiple substrings in `message`.

Comment: Yes @tshiono, in fact that was a crucial mistake in my answer, thank you for pointing that out!